# Visual Studio .net-core missing security tab

Tags: visual-studio, security, .net-core, clickonce

I am struggling with the following:

I have a .net-core (6.0 to be exact, but it doesn't matter, same applies to 5.0) application that I am deploying with ClickOnce.

Problem is: I want to control security options (which includes among others Full-Trust). In my particular case I am interested in specifying the [FileIOPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) flag.

Whenever I reference the Microsoft documentation on changing security settings, the page that I will usually come across is: [To enable ClickOnce security settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-enable-clickonce-security-settings?view=vs-2022#to-enable-clickonce-security-settings).

However, I am not seeing in Visual Studio (currently using 2022, but same thing for 2019) any option, tab or whatsoever for 'Security'. It really puzzles me.

Any suggestion, anyone, please?

Comment: CAS was deprecated over 11 years ago, it is removed completely for .NETCore.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#code-access-security-cas

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated:

As Hans said:

CAS was deprecated over 11 years ago, it is removed completely for [.NETCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#code-access-security-cas).

### [ClickOnce applications are based on the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/code-access-security-for-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022#default-clickonce-code-access-security)

#### .Net Framework

[image]

#### .Net 6.0

[image]

Currently we have no way to access the security tab in .net.

### It may be a problem with （.Net）. It is recommended that you could report the problem in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).